# Loop through array when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to loop through and array of months. Every time the next button is clicked it will go to the next month and vice versa for previous month. I'm confused about how to use a forEach statement for this. Maybe this is not the best choice and I should use the map function.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];

  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState(months[0]);

  
months.forEach(function(month){
  function handleClick(){
    setHeadingText(month);
  }


});
  


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The month is {headingText}</h1>
      <button>Previous Month</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next Month</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-blackburn-opqdv?file=/src/App.js:0-514

Comment: Your code sandbox code is different than what you have posted here. Which is your latest version?

Comment: Sorry my bad, code sandbox is my latest

Comment: You should not and do not need to use a for each loop. You should use a stored index value and increment or decrement based on the appropriate button click. 

Any other implementation would be inefficient. See all the answers below using an index value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around in your sandbox for a minute. Using hooks I created variable in state that we can use to index into the array.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];

  //lets declare a new state variable we'll call index that 
  //we can update in handleClick and use to access months
  const [i, incrementIndex] = useState(0)
  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState(`${months[i]}`);

  function handleClick() {
    setHeadingText(`${months[i + 1]}`);
    incrementIndex(i + 1)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The month is {headingText}</h1>
      <button>Previous Month</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next Month</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Maybe another conditional statement for the previous month that decrements the index variable in state.

Comment: Noob question but what is the $ for in the useState?

Comment: Accompanied with back-ticks, the $ is for String interpolation of a variable. ```https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals```

Answer (score 0):

You're off to a good start. What you want to do is have a "selectedIndex" as your state - this would hold the index of the selected month. You would also have logic for disabling buttons when the `selectedIndex` is on the edge of the array:

```
export default function App() {
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
  const handlePrevClick = useCallback(() => 
    setSelectedIndex((selectedIndex) => selectedIndex - 1), 
  [/* Note: no dependencies needed */])
  const handleNextClick = useCallback(() => 
    setSelectedIndex((selectedIndex) => selectedIndex + 1), 
  [/* Note: no dependencies needed */])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The month is {months[selectedIndex]}</h1>
      <button disabled={selectedIndex === 0} onClick={handlePrevClick}>Previous Month</button>
      <button disabled={selectedIndex === months.length - 1} onClick={handleNextClick}>Next Month</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not downvoting, however, `setSelectedIndex` and `selectedIndex` should be specified as dependencies of `useCallback`.

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko They don't have to be. React [guarantees function identity for the setter and is therefore not needed for `useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate). I'm also using a function in the setter so that `selectedIndex` is not a dependency for the callback. Please don't downvote this as it is a correct answer. Using this technique, the click handlers are only generated once on initial render and never again after that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I haven't been aware of it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need neither of them.

You could keep the current month index in the state: `const [month, setMonth] = useState(0);`,
then, inside of `handleClick` handler, increment the index:

```
function handleClick() {
    setMonth((month + 1) % months.length);
  }
```

Here is a complete example, based on your snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];

export default function App() {
  const [month, setMonth] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setMonth((month + 1) % months.length);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The month is {months[month]}</h1>
      <button>Previous Month</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next Month</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need a foreach, you could create two functions one for going ahead and one to go back. Also, consider index limitations due to array

```
export default function App() {
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];

  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState("Meow");
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  function handlePreviousClick() {
    if (index > 0) {
      setIndex(index - 1);
    }
    setHeadingText(months[index]);
  }

  function handleNextClick() {
    if (index < months.length - 1) {
      setIndex(index + 1);
    }
    setHeadingText(months[index]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The month is {headingText}</h1>
      <button onClick={handlePreviousClick}>previous Month</button>
      <button onClick={handleNextClick}>Next Month</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to easily switch between monthes it's better to use month index as a state

```
const MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
export function App() {
  const [currentMonthIndex, setCurrentMonthIndex] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    const nextIndex = (currentMonthIndex + 1) % MONTHS.length
    setCurrentMonthIndex(nextIndex)
  }, [setCurrentMonthIndex])

  const currentMonth = MONTHS[currentMonthIndex]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The month is {currentMonth}</h1>
      <button>Previous Month</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next Month</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote - but `setCurrentMonthIndex` - is not needed as a dependency ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)). You need to specify `currentMonthIndex` as a dependency. But if you use a function setter, you don't need any dependencies, and the click handler is only generated once on initial load (see my answer).